# Confusing binomial GLM output: highly significant, but with no positive classifications

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, interpretation

I try to investigate the influence from personal traits on drug use. I have 3 different classifications, to define if someone is a user or not.  One formula I used is this (cocaine contains only 0 and 1. neuroticism_org is a continuous variable):

```
glm.cocaine <- glm(cocaine ~ neuroticism_org, family="binomial", data=data)
```

[image: Here I've plotted the different models with different classifications. The first one is a weak and the last a strong classification]

I'm a bit confused about the first plot. The model classifies no users, no matter what neuroticism scores the person has, but the P-Value is highly significant. So I don't know how to interpret this, since this information seems inconsistent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `summary(glm.cocaine)`, and consider the reported coefficients.  It's hard for me to tell from what you've put, but I'll bet the predicted log odds goes up with neuroticism, but does so very slowly.  Moreover, when those predicted log odds are converted to predicted probabilities, they are very close to 0, even at your highest value of neuroticism.  It looks like you have very few positive cases for that model, and so predicted probabilities are always very low (from the reported accuracy, I gather only 22.06% of the subjects were users).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! That's right, only 28.2% were users... So the log odds is 0.0305. exp(0.0305) = 1.03. Does that mean that the odds p/(1-p) increases 0.30 for increasing the score by ten? That is very low, why is the P-Value still that significant?

Comment: @NicoPetermann, the p-value means that the pattern is sufficiently clear that the true slope isn't 0.